# Why doesn't std::atomic initialisation do atomic release so other threads can see the initialised value?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stl, atomic

Something very odd turned up during the thread sanitising of [proposed boost::concurrent_unordered_map](https://ci.nedprod.com/view/Boost%20Thread-Expected-Permit/job/Boost.Spinlock%20Test%20Linux%20GCC%204.8/doxygen/classboost_1_1spinlock_1_1concurrent__unordered__map.html) and is [recounted at this blog post](https://plus.google.com/109885711759115445224/posts/KhbHhU5J19B). In short, bucket_type looks like this:

```cpp
  struct bucket_type_impl
  {
    spinlock<unsigned char> lock;  // = 2 if you need to reload the bucket list
    atomic<unsigned> count; // count is used items in there
    std::vector<item_type, item_type_allocator> items;
    bucket_type_impl() : count(0), items(0) {  }
    ...
```

Yet the thread sanitiser claims that there is a race between the construction of a bucket_type and its first use, specifically when the count atomic is loaded from. It turns out that if you initialise a std::atomic<> via its constructor, [that initialisation is not atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic) and therefore the memory location is not atomically released and therefore not visible to other threads, which is counterintuitive given it's an atomic, and that most atomic operations default to memory_order_seq_cst. You must therefore explicitly do a release store after construction to initialise the atomic with a value visible to other threads.

Is there some extremely pressing reason why std::atomic with a value consuming constructor does not initialise itself with release semantics? If not, I think this is a library defect.

**Edit:** Jonathan's answer is the better for the history as to why, but ecatmur's answer links to Alastair's defect report on the matter, and how it was closed by simply adding a note to say construction offers no visibility to other threads. I'll therefore award the answer to ecatmur. Thanks to all who replied, I think the way is clear to ask for an extra constructor, it will at least stand out in the documentation that there is something unusual with the value consuming constructor.

**Edit 2:** I ended up raising this as a defect in the C++ language with the committee, and Hans Boehm who chairs the Concurrency part feels this is not an issue for the following reasons:

1. No present C++ compiler in 2014 treats consume as different to acquire. As you will never, in real world code, pass an atomic to another thread without going through some release/acquire, the initialisation of the atomic would be made visible to all threads using the atomic. I think this fine until compilers catch up, and before that the Thread Sanitiser will warn on this.
2. If you're doing mismatched consume-acquire-release like I am (I am using a release-inside-lock/consume-outside-lock atomic to speculatively avoid a release-acquire spinlock where it was unnecessary) then you're a big enough boy to know you must manually store release atomics after construction. That is probably a fair point.

Comment: How can you access the atomic variable from one thread when you don't know that it has been constructed yet in another thread? Surely you need some other way to synchronize the threads to ensure it's always constructed first, and that way would involve release semantics.

Comment: @interjay That's a separate matter. You can examine the source code at https://github.com/ned14/boost.spinlock/blob/master/spinlock.hpp#L438 if you'd like to see how.

Comment: @interjay: To summarise, yes you release after rehash, but that means not a jot when you consume (not acquire) a speculative read of count before deciding to lock.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because the converting constructor is `constexpr`, and `constexpr` functions can't have side effects such as atomic semantics.

In [DR846](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#846), Alastair Meredith writes:

> I'm not sure if the initialization is implied by use of constexpr keyword (which restricts the form of a constructor) but even if that is the case, I think it is worth spelling out explicitly as the inference would be far too subtle in that case.

The resolution for that defect (by Lawrence Crowl) was to document the constructor with the note:

> [*Note:* Construction is not atomic. *—end note*]

The note was then expanded to the current wording, giving an example of a possible memory race (via `memory_order_relaxed` operations communicating the address of the atomic) in [DR1478](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#1478).

The reason that the converting constructor needs to be `constexpr` is (primarily) to allow static initialization. In [DR768](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#768) we see:

> Further discussion: why is the ctor labeled "constexpr"? Lawrence [Crowl] said this permits the object to be statically initialized, and that's important because otherwise there would be a race condition on initialization.

So: making the constructor `constexpr` eliminates race conditions on static-lifetime objects, at the cost of a race in dynamic-lifetime objects that only occurs in *fairly* contrived situations, since for a race to occur the memory location of the dynamic-lifetime atomic object must be communicated to another thread in a way that does not result in the *value* of the atomic object being also synchronized to that thread.

Comment: I have always felt that constexpr should have been overloadable personally, but I guess that ship has probably sailed. I also disagree it's a contrived situation, my concurrent_unordered_map can concurrent rehash during which it constructs new atomic counts as it created new buckets. These then could race on other threads using those buckets, though I should seriously doubt that would actually ever happen in the real world given the amount of code and locks and unlocks between the two.

Comment: Hmm. I take your point above about how a race could occur; I guess it's not that contrived. I like your proposal for a two-argument constructor (I was thinking the same thing); perhaps you might propose it?

Answer (score 12):

That is an intentional design choice (there's even a note in the standard warning about it) and I think it was done in an attempt to be compatible with C.

The C++11 atomics were designed so that they could be used by WG14 for C as well, using the non-member functions such as `atomic_load` with types such as `atomic_int` rather than the member functions of the C++-only `std::atomic<int>`. In the original design, the `atomic_int` type has no special properties and atomicity is only achieved through `atomic_load()` and other functions. In that model `atomic_init` is not an atomic operation, it just initializes a POD. Only a subsequent `atomic_store(&i, 1)` call would be atomic.

In the end, WG14 decided to do things differently, adding the `_Atomic` specifier which makes the `atomic_int` type have magic properties. I'm not sure whether that means initialization of C atomics could be atomic (as it stands, `atomic_init` in C11 and C++11 is documented to be non-atomic), so maybe the C++11 rule is unnecessary. I suspect people will argue that there are good performance reason to keep initialization non-atomic, as interjay's comment above says, you need to send some notification to the other thread that the obejct is constructed and ready to be read from, so that notification could introduce the necessary fencing. Doing it once for the `std::atomic` initialization and then a second time to say the object is constructed could be wasteful.

Comment: I have no issue with the default constructor of atomic not doing anything - after all, you get uninitialised bits. Where I struggle is where with an explicit construction from some value that that value is not released to be visible to other threads.

Comment: For example, why doesn't std::atomic have a (t, std::memory_order order=std::memory_order_seq_cst) constructor? That would fit with the rest of the API.

Comment: @NiallDouglas defaulting `order` would collide with the existing constructor, but a two-argument constructor sounds good and would allow `atomic` to remain a literal type. I assume the semantics would be `atomic(t, order) { store(t, order); }`?

Comment: Could you give an example of the use of atomic initialization?

Answer (score 7):

I'd say, it's because a construction is never a thread communication operation: When you construct an object, you fill formerly uninitialized memory with sensible values. There is no way for another thread to tell whether that operation has finished *unless it is explicitely communicated by the constructing thread*. If you race with construction anyway, you immediately have undefined behavior.

Since the creating thread must explicitly publish its success on constructing a value before another thread can be allowed to use it, there is simply no point in synchronizing constructors.